# Main difference between Schema.org 'logo' and 'image' properties

Tags: seo, google-search, images, schema.org, rich-snippets

What is the difference between the `logo` and `image` properties?

If you go to the [`Brand` schema](https://schema.org/Brand), you will notice properties for `logo` and `image`. Is there any difference between these 2 properties? When would you use both or one over the other? How does/would Google represent them?

Currently I am making use of `logo` which just represents the logo/image of a brand. But I am not sure when (if needed) to use `image` if I already use logo? Which is the correct property to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`logo` property](http://schema.org/logo) is a sub-property of the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image). That means that whenever you use `logo`, you are implicitly also using `image`.

And `logo` can currently only be used for a few types (`Brand`, `Organization`, `Place`, `Product`, `Service`), while `image` is defined for `Thing`, so it can be used everywhere.

It does not necessarily have to make sense to use both properties for a type. Schema.org always lists both, even if there wouldn’t be a situation where using both would make sense.
But there are of course cases where it does make sense, for example for `Organization`: `logo` for the organization’s logo, `image` for a group photo of the organization’s team.

If you have an image "of the item" (that’s how [`image`](http://schema.org/image) is defined), decide if it’s the logo of that item. If not, use `image`, if yes, use `logo`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use it where you have both a logo and a feature image on a page, like this:

[image: Crocs]

This page isn't actually marked up like this, but you could set `logo` for the actual Crocs logo on the right, and `image` for the banner featuring the product on the left.